# Calculating compass Direction of a 3D current vector

Tags: trigonometry

I have a set of current data that is given as a series of 3 dimensional vectors (X,Y,Z). With X being the East-West flow, Y being the North-South flow, and Z being the vertical flow.

In the past I have been able to ignore the z flow, so calculating the current speed and direction has been relatively easy.

```
Speed= sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
Direction= arctan(y/x)
```

So if

```
x= -0.017112
y= -0.17241
```

Then my Speed should be 0.173 and my Direction should be 84 degrees.

But now I need to add in the z axis, and I'm not sure how to do this.

Speed is easy- Speed= sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2). But I'm not sure how to get the same kind of directional data.

So for instance, if

```
x= 0.29

y=-0.095

z=1.392
```

What would be my speed and direction?

Comment: I can cheat and use a program to calculate the speed and direction for the above three vectors. Using the program I get a speed of 0.305 and the direction is 108.14. I have no idea how they get these numbers, especially considering I calculated the speed to be 1.425058. Any idea how the program is calculating speed and direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in compass heading, you can ignore $z$ as you have been doing.  You could add in elevation if you want, using $\arctan \frac z{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$.  There are other formats for three dimensional direction, like direction cosines.  Your equation for speed is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you want one angle as your direction, you can use $\theta$ between $0$ and $2\pi$ in the inside of some 2-dimensional subspace spanned by some linear combination of two orthonormal vectors generated from a change of basis from the vectors you gave.  Use $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{e}_i = |\vec{v}||\vec{e}_i|\cos\theta = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}\cos\theta$ to obtain $\theta$.  Or did you want multiple coordinates?  If that's the case, you can do some fancy trigonometry.  Try drawing a bunch of right triangles amongst the vectors that you've been given, including perhaps $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, $\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}$, and $\sqrt{y^2 + z^2}$.  The solution will fall right out.  Remember that the second angle must be measured between $0$ and $\pi$ though!